# How save an string output after a for loop in python with pandas and csv modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I have the following for loop:

```
    for titles in titles:
        title = titles.xpath("a/text()").extract()
        link = titles.xpath("a/@href").extract()
        print(title, link)
```

How can I dump the title and link into a formmated .csv file?

Comment: I am pretty sure that this a well-hashed out issue that you can Google pretty much as you typed it.

Comment: I tried several things, even with numpy and pandas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the python CSV module. Look here for more information: [Writing List of Strings to Excel CSV File in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916542/writing-list-of-strings-to-excel-csv-file-in-python).

Here is an example for your problem:

```
import csv
results = []

# your code... also add this to your for loop.
    results.append([title, link])

csv_file = open("csv_file.csv",'wb')
wr = csv.writer(csv_file)
for row in results:
    wr.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help preston!... when I tried this approach the csv file is blank... I got the following exception:`File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/scrapy_tests/ttest/spiders/test.py", line 28, in parse
    wr.writerow(row)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str`

Comment: Change `'wb'` to `'w'`, can't see why you opened in binary mode.

Comment: You can use either I think, the examples I found used binary writing so that's what I used.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)):

```
...
doc_path = "path/to/doc.csv" # must exist, first folder on the place
                             # where you are running the script!
with open(doc_path, 'a') as doc:
    for entry in titles:
        title = entry.xpath("a/text()").extract()
        link  = entry.xpath("a/@href").extract()
        print(title, link)
        doc.write(str(title)+','+str(link)+'\n')
```

Comment: Thanks berna!... what about something with pandas?

Comment: You could use something like [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), but even people using pandas use traditional `write` ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017072/pandas-read-csv-and-filter-columns-with-usecols)).

Answer (score 1):

Use a [csv writer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Basic usage:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["title", "link"])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = []
for titles in titles:
    title = titles.xpath("a/text()").extract()
    link = titles.xpath("a/@href").extract()
    print(title, link)
    result += [title + ',' + link + '\n']

with open("result.csv" "w+") as f:
    f.writelines(result)
```

Comment: Thanks!... I got this exception: ` line 24, in parse
    result += [title + ',' + link + '\n']
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`